# ¿Como ajustar una imagen en fancybox2?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estoy usando Fancybox2, ¿alguien podría ayudarme a ajustar una imagen de modo que se visualice completa sin que se necesite scroll para visualizarla toda?

Mi imagen al abrila con Fancybox se visualiza asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código en Fancybox es este:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      'width':980,
      'height':980,
      'type':'iframe',
      'autoScale':'false',
      'titleShow': 'true',
      'position': 'auto',
      helpers : { 
        overlay: {
          'transparent':'true',
          opacity: 0.8, // or the opacity you want 
          css: {'background-color': 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)',} 
        } // overlay 
      } // helpers
   });
  });
```

Utilizo ese `height` y ese `width` para poder visualizarla bien pero no se ajusta, ¿algún consejo?

Comment: ¿Debe ser un iframe?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: Bueno, creo que ya entendiste mi pregunta, con la respuesta que te dieron abajo.

Comment: Si ya logre entenderlo, te referías al type, ¿sabes como colocar texto debajo de la imagen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando el `type` incorrecto, intenta usando `image`. Te dejo algunos ejemplos con diferentes tamaños de imagen.

Imagen de 400x400:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  'type':'image',
  'title': 'Imagen de 400x400',
  'titleShow': 'true',
  'helpers' : { 
      'overlay': {
          'transparent':'true',
          'opacity': 0.8,
          'css': {'background-color': 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)',} 
    } 
  } 
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/400x400" style="max-width: 350px;">
    Imagen
</a>
```

Imagen de 800x800:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  'type':'image',
  'title': 'Imagen de 800x800',
  'titleShow': 'true',
  'helpers' : { 
      'overlay': {
          'transparent':'true',
          'opacity': 0.8,
          'css': {'background-color': 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)',} 
    } 
  } 
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/800x800" style="max-width: 350px;">
    Imagen
</a>
```

Imagen de 1200x1200:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  'type':'image',
  'title': 'Imagen de 1200x1200',
  'titleShow': 'true',
  'helpers' : { 
      'overlay': {
          'transparent':'true',
          'opacity': 0.8,
          'css': {'background-color': 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)',} 
    } 
  } 
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/1200x1200" style="max-width: 350px;">
    Imagen
</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ese era el problema el "type", otra consulta, ¿como puedo añadir texto como una descripción del producto?

Comment: @AlejandroRuiz he actualizado mi respuesta, si te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada con el check al costado de mi respuesta.

Comment: listo, puedes ayudarme con la parte del texto como descripción del producto? ¿donde podría colocarlo? y ¿Cómo?

Comment: @AlejandroRuiz está en mi respuesta, tienes que usar el parámetro `title`